# The best way to encode user password in Symfony 3?

Tags: php, symfony

I know that I can use this encoder:

```
$encoder = $this->container->get('security.password_encoder');
$encoded = $encoder->encodePassword($user, $plainPassword);
```

But when I should use it?
I can encode password before calling setPassword() method. Or I can encode password in setPassword() method. Or maybe I should create a custom doctrine data type which will encode password before save to database? Or something else? Which variant is better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't use any bundle for users (like [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle)) I would suggest to take advantage of doctrine's [events](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html) `preInsert` and `preUpdate`

That way you can centralize your code and be sure that every time a user is "written" into db, your operation will be performed.

### Please pay attention

If `$plainPassword` hasn't a value into `preUpdate`, maybe you should perform some actions and, more in general, I bet you need to implement some logic to avoid encode a password that's already encoded

Answer (score 0):

The practice is to store passwords in DB in encrypted form. Then during login get the password from the user, encrypt it again, read the encrypted password from the DB, compare the two; pass/fail depending on match/mismatch.

Comment: I do believe that you should NOT encrypt your passwords because it's a reversible operation. You mush hash it, than it will be not reversible.

Comment: Yes, I stand corrected. The flow I described above was for one way hash, but I used the word encryption.